# Should a command line argument for increasing memory limits count towards byte/character count?

Tags: discussion, scoring

Most Java interpreters have a predefined memory limit. However, it's a `-X` setting - an implementation specific setting.

With C, the call stack is usually heavily limited. There's usually a compiler setting to increase this limit. This is implementation-specific and as far as the C spec is concerned, there's no call stack limit.

Should implementation-specific options to increase the memory limit count towards the byte/character count? In other words, should limitations of the physical world count towards the byte count?

Comment: In many C implementations, the stack limit can be set at runtime (it's specified by the operating system, and there's often a way to tune it). That means that it wouldn't need to be set at compile time. Java is similar; the `-X` flag isn't given to `javac` (the compiler), but rather to `java` (the runtime). In this sense it's a bit different from the typical compiler flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## It depends.

We usually require submissions to work only up to the limits of the compiler/hardware, as long as the underlying algorithm works for arbitrary input.

Unless the challenge specifically says otherwise, if a solution requires a wider integer type, a higher recursion limit, a bigger stack limit, more bytes of RAM than there are atoms in the observable universe, etc. for some/most/all of the test cases, you don't even need the `-X` flag, so you don't have to add it to your byte count.

However, if the challenge spec requires your solution to work for specific test cases, the extra flags *should* count, as would the required import statements to work with arbitrary-precision integers.

Comment: But they're implementation-specific flags! E.g. a different JVM or a different compiler would work just fine without the flags. Do I use the friendlier compiler/interpreter as the language, rather than the language itself? (e.g. "GCC - 240 bytes" rather than "C - 240 bytes")

Comment: As far as PPCG is concerned, the implementation *is* the language. If there is a compiler that doesn't require the flag, you don't need it in your submission. Just mention the compiler you used and you'll be fine.